# What modifications should be made to this regex for allowing space?

Tags: javascript, regex

Below are two javascript variables which I am using for client side validation. Can someone help modifying these codes so they allow space too. Only space and not any extra speacial character.

```
 var alphabet=/^[A-z]+$/;
 var alphanum=/^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
```

Comment: Read the basic documentation on character classes, which are those things inside square brackets. While you're doing that, also check what `[A-z]` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `\s` to allow space character in regex:

```
var alphabet=/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/; 
var alphanum=/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/i;
```

Also, change your regex to be right:

```
a-z // Allows lowercase
A-Z // Allows uppercase

A-z // Incorrect
```